# How to make failed Firebase Cloud Functions automatically retry on deployment?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm having a problem with my functions. There's a "Quota Exceeded" error and I want to make my failed functions automatically retry on deploying.

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and up-voting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Comment: hello. thank you for the help. sorry, I can't upvote I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

1. With Cloud Functions for Firebase, you can enable retries in the
   code for a function. To do this for a background function such as
   functions.foo.onBar(myHandler);, use runWith and configure a failure
   policy:

   ```
   functions.runWith({failurePolicy: true}).foo.onBar(myHandler);
   ```

   [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries#enabling_and_disabling_retries)
2. To enable retries via the gcloud command-line tool, include the
   --retry flag when deploying your function

   gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME --retry FLAGS...

   To set specific conditions while retrying the function automatically can
   refer
   [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries)